# Robot Block Command

Tags: java, algorithm

> ### Problem
>
> We have a robot that can pickup blocks from a stash, move them
> horizontally and lower them in place. There are 10 positions available
> to lower blocks number 0 to 9. Each position can hold up to 15 blocks.
>
> The robot understands the commands 'P', 'M' and 'L':
>
> - P: Pickup from the stash and move to position 0
> - M: Move to the Next Position
> - L: Lower the block
>
> The robot is safe to operate and very forgiving:
>
> - There are always blocks in the stash (Pickup always gets a block)
> - If the robot already holds a block, Pickup will reset position to 0
> - The robot will not go beyond position 9, Trying to move further does nothing
> - Lowering the block on a pile of 15 does nothing
> - Lowering without a block does nothing
> - Robot ignores any command that is not 'P', 'M','L'
>
> Implement a function that takes a String of commands for the robot.
> The function should output String representing the number of blocks
> (in hexadecimal) at each position after running all the commands
>
> [image]

---

### Solution

I have implemented it and it works fine and all but I feel like this is not the correct way.

Key errors I feel are how I determine Hexadecimal values from A to F. What is the correct way of doing this other than using a hashmap?

Also, processing of each command using switch-case feels so verbose as well.

Has anyone solved this problem before? What's the optimal way of doing this?

```
private static int[] stash = new int[10];
private static HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    map.put(10, "A");
    map.put(11, "B");
    map.put(12, "C");
    map.put(13, "D");
    map.put(14, "E");
    map.put(15, "F");

    String command = "PMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMMMLPMLPMMLPMMMMMMMMMMLPMMMMMMMMMML";
    executeCommand(command);
}

private static void executeCommand(String command) {
    int block = 0;
    int stashLocation = 0;
    for (Character c : command.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'P':
                if (block == 0) {
                    block = 1;
                } else {
                    stashLocation = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 'M':
                if (stashLocation < 9) {
                    stashLocation++;
                }
                break;
            case 'L':
                if (block != 0 && stash[stashLocation] < 15) {
                    stash[stashLocation] = stash[stashLocation] + 1;
                    block = 0;
                    stashLocation = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    Arrays.stream(stash).forEach(val -> {
        if (map.containsKey(val)) {
            System.out.print(map.get(val));
        } else {
            System.out.print(val);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `P` and `L` actions do not match the problem statement (`P` should _always_ move arm to position 0, `L` should _not_ change the arm position).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't really take advantage of the **object oriented** features of Java. You have everything in one file with one object manipulating the state of several things: The robotic arm, the stash, and the piles. This makes the code tightly coupled and hard to change.
Generally, your variable naming is clear and follows Java best practices: `block`, `stashLocation`, etc. Personally I'd use a boolean for the block, not an int, as your robot either has or doesn't have a block. That'd also clean up the if clauses:

```
boolean hasBlock = false;
// other code here
if (hasBlock) {
    doSomethingWithBlock();
}
```

Regarding your specific questions:

### Hexadecimal values

Use Java's print formatting functions String.format and it's likes:
`String hex = String.format("%02X", 15)` will assign the value 0xF to the variable hex. Read up on [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and the [format specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

### Command processing

For this case, I think it's fine to use a switch case to act on the commands. Somehow, you **have** to identify each single command char, and a switch is a good way here. What I would do, though, is break out the actual commands into separate functions, and only call them from the case statement:

```
for (char cmd : command.toCharArray()) {
        switch (cmd) {
            case 'P': 
                pickup(); 
                break;
            case 'M':
                move();
                break;
            case 'L':
                lower();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.format("Unknown command %c", cmd);
        }
    }

    void pickup() { /* function definition here */ }
    void move() { /* function definition here */ }
    void lower() { /* function definition here */ }
```

Of course, one could get fancy here and map the command chars to a [lambda](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html#lambda-parameters) or something, but that might be overkill. A small improvement could be to use an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for the commands, and switch on that.

### My implementation

This was a fun task, and here is my implementation. I split the Robot and the Piles into own classes, coordinated by the Main class. I thought about separating the Stash also, but since it had next to no business logic, I left in in the Robot (just setting hasBlock to true in pickup). By using objects, the printing of status can be "automated" by using the `toString()` method, as I've done below.

Piles.java

```
public class Piles {

    public Piles(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width - 1; // - 1 because of zreo indexing
        this.height = height;
        piles = new int[width];
    }

    public boolean drop(int position) {
        boolean positionValid = position <= (this.width - 1);
        boolean pileAvailable = this.piles[position] < this.height;

        if (positionValid && pileAvailable) {
            piles[position]++;
        }

        return positionValid && pileAvailable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < piles.length; i++) {
            res.append(String.format("%d: %02x ", i, piles[i]));
        }
        return res.toString();
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    /* PRIVATE */
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    private final int[] piles;

}
```

Robot.java

```
public class Robot {

    public Robot(Piles piles) {
        this.maxWidth = piles.getWidth();
        this.piles = piles;

    }

    public void execute(String command) {
        for (char cmd : command.toCharArray()) {
            switch (cmd) {
                case 'P': 
                    pickup(); 
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    move();
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    lower();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.format("Unknown command %c", cmd);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(piles);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Robot is at position %d %s a block", position, hasBlock ? "with" : "without");
    }

    /* PRIVATE */

    private final Piles piles;
    private final int maxWidth;
    private int position = 0;
    private boolean hasBlock = false;

    /* Pick up a block from the stash.
     * The rules are:
     * - the stash is never empty
     * - after pickup, move to position 0
     * - if the robot already holds a block, reset position to 0
     */
    private void pickup() {
        hasBlock = true;
        position = 0;
    }


    /* Advance the robot one step
     * The rules are:
     * - the robot will not go beyond maxWidth, trying to move further does nothing.
     */
    private void move() {
        position = Math.min(++position, maxWidth);
    }


    /* Lower a block to the pile at the current location.
     * The rules are:
     * - lowering the block on a pile of 15 does nothing
     * - lowering without a block does nothing
     */
    private void lower() {
        if (piles.drop(position)) {
            hasBlock = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Robot robot = new Robot(new Piles(10, 15));
        System.out.println(robot);

        robot.execute("PMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPMLPML");
        robot.execute("PLPLPMMMMML");

    }
}
```